# How is it possible to use subscript and superscript together on an Axis-Label?

Tags: r, plot, expression, gnu

I am trying to add an axis label to my plot, which contains both - a subscript and a superscript. The outcome should look something like this:

[image: example]

So far I have tried the following:

```
expression("T*"["AL,e"])
expression("T"^"*"["AL,e"])
```

The results are ok, but not exactly what I was looking for initially. Therefore my question is: How can a subscript and a superscript be added to an expression on the same spot?

It is important for the superscript to appear exactly on top of the subscript, not just next or close to it.

Comment: Maybe try `expression({"T"^"*"}["AL,e"])`.

Comment: or `expression("T"["AL,e"]^"*")`

Comment: (dupe first hit when googling "r expression subscript superscript")

Comment: This gives me the same result as `expression("T"^"*"["AL,e"])`. What is the curved brackets usual function in an expression?

Comment: I am looking for a way, to display the superscript on top of the subscript, not next to it. The other question/answer only allows me to use them next to each other.

Comment: @user8912937 They are not next to each other. I suggest `expression(italic(T)["AL,e"]^"*")` however, you cannot the T and the A as in your desired output. You might have to use LaTeX.

Comment: ^overlap is missing

Comment: Thank you. I think I will try to do it through LaTeX then.